# template.queryselector or queryselectorAll is returning undefined

Tags: lightning

I am trying to access elements in js of component by using template.querySelector() or template.querySelectorAll() but those were returning undefined. Below is the html code

```
<template>
   <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label={studentInfo}> 
            <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                <lightning-layout-item size="1" flexibility="auto">
                    Age:
                </lightning-layout-item>
            
                <lightning-layout-item  size="5" flexibility="auto no-grow">
                    <template for:each={ageValues} for:item="age" for:index="index">
                        <lightning-badge key={age.id} label={age.title} class="ageCSS"></lightning-badge>
                    </template>
                   
                </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto">
                    <p>Secondary age:</b>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item size="5" flexibility="auto">
                    <template for:each={secondarySchoolAgeValues} for:item="secondaryAge" for:index="index">
                        <lightning-badge key={secondaryAge.id} label={secondaryAge.title} class="ageCSS"></lightning-badge>
                    </template>
            </lightning-layout>

        <br/>
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={studentList}
                columns={studentColumns}
                hide-checkbox-column>
            </lightning-datatable>
        
    <div class="slds-clearfix">
                <lightning-button label="View All" title="View All"  class="slds-float_right" onclick={handleViewAll}></lightning-button>
            </div>
</lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

In JS file for handleViewAll method below is the code,

```
handleViewAll(){
        var tabval = this.template.querySelector("lightning-tabset");
            console.log('tabval ', this.tabval);
            var inputs = this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-badge");
            console.log(' inputs ', this.inputs);
            var queryInput = this.template.querySelector(".ageCSS");
            console.log('query value ', this.queryInput);
    }
```

for all console.log statements it is returning undefined. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Note: this is a child component. To my knowledge there is nothing related to parent component for queryselector to return undefined.

Please suggest or correct my code in order to get the right values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.X` is not the same as `X`. The former belongs to the object's scope, while the latter belongs to the local function scope. Try:

```
console.log('tabval',tabval);
...
console.log('inputs',inputs);
...
console.log('query value', queryInput);
```

Comment: Good catch. I was checking the availability of items inside another components slots... which must work I suppose.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Indeed. The template that defines the child component owns that component, even within another component's slots, so the queries should work as expected.

Comment: @sfdxfox, thank you very much.

Comment: hi @sfdxfox,
If you have some time can you please take a look at the question

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/407167/how-to-highlight-badges-based-on-column-values-in-lightning-datatable

Can you suggest or advice how to achieve it. Right now I was thinking of using querySelectorAll by class for the badge against the result data for the column. 
If there is a better way please suggest. Thank you very much

Comment: @getty I'd love to help, but there's no code to look at. At minimum, I would want to see the markup for the badges and the renderedCallback code you've written so far.